# is it possible to stop manually dev server from jenkins

Tags: jenkins

my dev server is installed in jboss aplication server(linux). is it possible to stop manually dev server from jenkins. whenever developer wants depolyment at that time only i have to stop server and deploy artifacts in to dev server.All these operations is possible from jenkins.i already have scripts to stop and start the server. But i dont know how to configure in jenkins.

Comment: please provide some details I think I am missing a point here. If you really wanna to do it manually then why are you using Jenkins? And what do you wanna configure in Jenkins -Dev server or scripts. Please elaborate.

Comment: i want to run scripts from jenkins.i already have scripts to stop and start server. but i don't know how to configure it in jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your jenkins is also on linux, use "Execute shell" build step and in there connect to your server and execute command:

For example:

```
ssh user@server "remote_script_command"
```